# cp: cannot create directory : No such file or directory

Tags: linux

I am trying to copy a folder from a source to a destination but I am getting the following error:

```
cp: cannot create directory ‘/home/Workspace/Release/addons/’: No such file or directory
```

I entered the following command:

```
cp -R /home/Workspace/Dev/user1/addons/account /home/Workspace/Release/addons/
```

I tried the same command with different folders and it worked fine.

```
cp -R /home/Desktop/file_transfer/f1/ff1 /home/Desktop/file_transfer/f2/
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Permissions for that directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x 363 user1 user1  16384 Sep 16 21:57 addons
```

Comment: Please post here permission of that directory .

Comment: I think the error is correct. You do not have the directory `/home/Workspace/Release/addons`,nor the `/home/Workspace/Release/` directory, so you should create one or both of those

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting a `permission denied` error.

Change the permissions of the addon directory using

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/Workspace/Release/addons/
```

Comment: Or /home/Workspace/Release/, perhaps a `mkdir -p `home/Workspace/Release/addons/` ` would help

Comment: Yes, the directory is there.

Comment: Thanks, it works if I enter the command manually but when I pass it, the command get seems to get divided and onto to the next line. Please see the Q2 in my question.

Answer (score 30):

It is probably because at least one of the directory of your path (/home/Workspace/Release/addons/) does not exist. cp will not create the addons directory (neither its parents of course), so ensure that the path really exists.

To create the path you can do:

```
mkdir -p /home/Workspace/Release/addons/
```

Comment: The `addon` directory exists.

Comment: `addon` or `addons`?